# Getting error "This action would increase the number of cells in the worksheet above the limit" with 50,000 cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to get a CSV downloaded from an URL into a new, empty Google sheet using script editor.

```
 var raw = UrlFetchApp.fetch(final_url, options).getContentText();
 var data = Utilities.parseCsv(raw, "|");
 Logger.log(data[0].length); /// 17 (columns)
 Logger.log(data.length); /// 2849 (rows)

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

As far as I understand it, I have a total of 48433 cells, but when I try to write it to the sheet, I get the error:

> This action would increase the number of cells in the workbook above the limit of 5000000 cells.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the value of `data.length` and `data[0].length`, if you log them?

Comment: It's commented in the code, 17 and 2849, just to make sure which dimensions I was working with.

Comment: How many cells are already in your sheet? Try in a new sheet perhaps

Comment: Could you try `Logger.log(data.every(function(row){return row.length === 17}))` to see whether  every row has 17 columns or only the first row

Comment: It returns "true". But I tried Logger.log(data.every(function(column){return column.length === 2850})) and it was false. But I don't understand why

Comment: It's a blank sheet.

Comment: Can you share a link to the CSV file?

Comment: *I tried Logger.log(data.every(function(column){return column.length === 2850})) and it was false.* ReNaming row as column won't give you columns, but that doesn't matter. How many rows  and columns in the blank sheet ? Make sure to create 3k rows and 18 columns and try again

Comment: I can't believe it was that easy. Thank you! I'd upvote it, but I don't think you can in an a comment.

Comment: Great..I'll add a answer.  Consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue:

Insufficient cells in the sheet to `setValues` data. And `setValues()` incorrectly throws the error

> This action would increase the number of cells in the workbook above the limit of 5000000 cells.

This might be due to the content of the csv file(and therefore the resulting array data). During testing, I was able to add 2800rowsx17 columns of data to a sheet with 1000rows x 26 columns without issues.

#### Solution:

- Manually increase the number of rows/columns in the sheet OR
- Try [sheet#insertRows](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertRows(Integer,Integer)) to insert rows before  calling `setValues`

#### Snippet:

```
sheet.insertRows(sheet.getLastRow(), data.length);
```

Comment: hi, i've tried to insert rows so there are more rows in the sheet than my python dataframe but still getting the error, any idea what's happening?

Comment: @user147529 Check the size of the array after parsing. Do follow my debug comments in the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58061314/getting-error-this-action-would-increase-the-number-of-cells-in-the-worksheet-a/58062493?noredirect=1#comment102519566_58061314

Comment: thanks, my data is in python, not google apps scripts. the shape is (49868, 11). i did manage to run the code by reducing the dataframe, however, i couldn't see the output in the sheet. perhaps i'll start another Q

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing the actual sheet and the CSV file we can only speculate as to what the issue is. My best guess is that you haven't taken into consideration that the 5,000,000 cells restriction applies to the entire "workbook". So if you have multiple tabs (sheets) then the sum of cells used across those sheets cannot exceed 5,000,000 cells.

Comment: My sheet is empty, and I only have one of them.

Comment: Are the rows in the CSV of variable length?

Comment: All the rows have the same length, 17.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend use pygsheets library. Google sheets will count as object lines and columns even blank ones. So, the first this i would do is delete blank rows and delete unused colums as well and retry the process. [deleting sheets rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRBMi.png)

After that, you should be able to insert some data (try with few lines first). Right after, try to build a function or use a library to resize the sheet after all insertions or try to update the lines with the new data.

**If using python:**

Pygsheets has methods to insert, update or append data to spreadsheet [pygsheets documentation](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/worksheet.html#pygsheets.Worksheet). If you use append method, remember of adding "overwrite=True", this will prevent the creation of blank lines after the data every time. If you use update methods you're fine and if you want to user inserts methods for any reason, i would suggest use resize methods after all to trim the spreadsheet to you data and prevent this error again.

If there're any doubt regarding the usage of pygsheets, there's nothing better than the documentation, but [this link](https://medium.com/game-of-data/play-with-google-spreadsheets-with-python-301dd4ee36eb) can help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, which comes up often. I'll explain what bug I had and I'm pretty sure it matches this. So for the pleasure, here is the story:
I have a CSV with employee IDs, made up of 3 letters so for example SRA, JPO, WKU etc... and in my sheet, I have tabs with these IDs.
So basically I read the CSV, I group the data according to the IDs and I inject it into the corresponding tabs.

But sometimes several employees have the same initials and to distinguish them, there is an extra number. So we have ids such as JMA5 or SPO2.
I do the injection and boom, here I am with the Google error indicating that I exceed a million cells!

I look at my tabs and I see that the tabs with names containing a number are not filled in. Then, when I open the SRA tab, I realize that thousands of columns have been added!!! And when I scroll, I arrive at the JMA column and line 5, I see the data that should have gone into my JMA5 tab!!! And as Google Sheet counts as cells both empty and full cells, with as many columns, indeed, I reach the limit....
Concretely if I read the SRA tab and then I do an insertion giving JMP5 as "range", the insertion is done on SRA!JMA5 which adds columns.
the solution is explained "very discreetly" in the Google docs: when the tabs have names containing spaces or alpha-numeric characters, they must be surrounded with single quotation marks.
So

```
$range = "JMA5";
```

won't work because it will inject into the last used tab, at JMA5 location (colume JMA, line 5). For it to actually inject into the JMA5 tab (append values), you have to write

```
$id = "JMA5";
$range = "'".$id."'";
```

And this is the same when you indicate cells: 'JMA5'!A1 for exemple.