# This action would increase the number of cells in the workbook above the limit of 10000000 cells Google-Apps-Script

Tags: google-apps-script

- I am trying to import `base-64` `CSV` into Google Apps Script.
- I am facing the below error

```
Error   
Exception: This action would increase the number of cells in the workbook above the limit of 10000000 cells.
myFunction  @ Code.gs:16
```

- Followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58061314/getting-error-this-action-would-increase-the-number-of-cells-in-the-worksheet-a), but not coming to a solution.
- Code [new-base-64-string](https://textdoc.co/vgxpARnQtDJ4u85B)

```
function myFunction() {

  var csv_string = [base-64-string];
  
  var decoded = Utilities.base64Decode(csv_string); // decoded string
  
  var string = Utilities.newBlob(decoded).getDataAsString(); // csv string

  var array = Utilities.parseCsv(string) // 2d array

  console.log(array.length);
  console.log(array[0].length);

  Logger.log(array.every(function(row){return row.length === 1}));

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,array.length,array[0].length).setValues(array);
}
```

- Log for `console.log(array.length);` `1`
- Log for `console.log(array[0].length);` `12537`
- Log for `Logger.log(array.every(function(row){return row.length === 1}));` `false`

[CSV Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r3Wto2EO0qYCyDnP_8ouJ7xlhiUfTm_RgaPWe3e5lmY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: When I saw your sample base64 data, it seems that the number of rows is 1747. And, unfortunately, I cannot understand "CSV Link". As a test, when I use the CSV data of your provided base64 data, no error occurs. I cannot replicate your issue. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue of `Exception: This action would increase the number of cells in the workbook above the limit of 10000000 cells.`?

Comment: It went away, it was there for ```5 sheets``` I made and on ```6th sheet``` it went away. Maybe some bug.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: @Tanaike the issue persists with this particular [base-64](https://file.io/C4r60ORsHzGa)

Comment: [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1In95n_JPIoeCoSKdDIUYyDHnqbUU9AeVJxwmc_OFoyg/edit?usp=sharing) you can copy my google-sheet and try

Comment: When I saw your new base64 data, it seems that it is not CSV data. It's JSON data. So, I'm worried that you miscopied your sample data. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike you can check with the ```apps script``` attached with my google sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw the data decoded from your base64, it seems that the data is JSON data which is not CSV data. When your provided base64 data is correct, I think that the reason of your current issue is due to this. So, in this case, can you provide your expected situation as the image? Because your JSON data is the nested JSON data. By this, I cannot know your expected situation. I apologize for this. When I could understand your expected situation, I think that I can propose a sample script.

Comment: I am giving ```csv``` as an input which is then send to python for some processing and then it returns the ```base-64``` string which in turn generates a ```csv```, but i want to generate a ```csv``` on ```google-sheets``` with the help of ```base-64``` string that i am getting in my json.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected result from your reply. Do you want to convert your JSON data to CSV data? If my understanding is correct, can you provide your expected sample CSV data? Because your data is nested JSON data. So, I cannot imagine your expected CSV data. I apologize for this, again.

Comment: No, the JSON contains a field ```Base64EncodedFile```, which contains a ```base-64``` string which I am using to convert it to ```csv``` You can find the json sample [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I9Liq1ePrqZXQlejMwpOu3q3VZo_7hCI/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your provided JSON data, you want to use the data by decoding the base64 data in your provided JSON data. If my understanding is correct, the decoded data is the nested JSON data as I have already mentioned in my comments. If you want to convert this JSON data to CSV data, can you provide your expected sample CSV data? Because I cannot imagine your expected CSV data. I apologize for this, again.

Comment: Expected [CSV](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zXAvza59_DCqaP5YvVChD5FdUEfWjV7h/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the sample output values. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I saw the data decoded from your base64, it seems that the data is JSON data which is not CSV data. I think that the reason for your current issue is due to this.

From your provided data, in order to parse the data, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var base64 = "###"; // Your provided base64 data.
  
  var decoded = Utilities.base64Decode(base64);
  var obj = JSON.parse(Utilities.newBlob(decoded).getDataAsString());
  var obj2 = JSON.parse(obj.Rows);
  var actualHeader = ["Transaction Date","Particulars","Amount","Cr/Dr","Balance","Transaction Type","Party Name","Charge Name","Charge Class"];
  var objHeader = ["Transaction_Date","Particulars","Amount","Cr_Dr","Balance","Transaction_Type","Normalized_Party_Name_Label","Normalized_Charge_Name_Label","Charge_Class"];
  var array = [actualHeader, ...obj2.map(o => objHeader.map(h => o[h] || ""))];
  
  // Here, the value is put to the active sheet.
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,array.length,array[0].length).setValues(array);
}
```

- `actualHeader` is from the data of your comment. `objHeader` is from the JSON data.
- If your provided JSON data of `https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I9Liq1ePrqZXQlejMwpOu3q3VZo_7hCI/view?usp=sharing` is used, `var base64` can be modified as follows.

  ```
    var data = DriveApp.getFileById("1I9Liq1ePrqZXQlejMwpOu3q3VZo_7hCI").getBlob().getDataAsString();
    var base64 = JSON.parse(data).Output.Augmented_Transactions.Base64EncodedFile;
  ```
- When this script is run, the base64 data is decoded and parse it as JSON data. And, create an array. And then, the array is put to the active sheet.
- If you want to convert `array` to CSV data, how about using `var csv = array.map(r => r.join(",")).join("\n")`?

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: this works, but wouldn't this only work for those file having particular headers and not for any file that I will receive on that url, right?

Comment: @Lav Sharma Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `but wouldn't this only work for those file having particular headers and not for any file that I will receive on that url, right?`, my proposed script is for your provided data. So, unfortunately, I cannot understand your additional question. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.